# Can I use a verb as an interrupter?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use a verb as an interrupter?

For instance, if I would like to mean:

> *He is said to be leaking secrets*

can I also express it like this?

> *He, is said, is leaking secrets*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but it can be expressed like this:

> *He, **it** is said, is leaking secrets.*

For every verb with tense, there needs to be a subject. Both instances of "is" are conjugated verbs, so they need subjects. It's not clear in your sentence whether "He" is the subject of the first or second "is". I guessed the second, and inserted a subject, "it", for the first.

Comment: "He is, it is said, leaking secrets" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @KateBunting: Actually I'd disagree that one is more idiomatic than the other - the difference is in emphasis rather than acceptability.

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe with different word choices that would be more idiomatic, but "is it is" makes for an awkward sentence. Maybe it _sounds_ better but it's not pleasant to read.

Comment: Or maybe just different word choice/construction altogether would be more idiomatic: "He is allegedly leaking secrets.".